# How to implement dynamic parameter estimation with missing data in Gekko?

Tags: python-3.x, differential-equations, nonlinear-optimization, gekko

Going back and forth through [the documentation](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#nonlinear-regression), I was able to set-up a  **dynamic parameter estimation** in Gekko.

Here's the code, with measurement values shown below (the file is named `MeasuredAlgebrProductionRate_30min_18h.csv` on my system, and uses `;`as separator):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO

#%% Read measurement data from CSV file
t_x_q_obs = np.genfromtxt('MeasuredAlgebrProductionRate_30min_18h.csv', delimiter=';')
#t_obs, x_obs, q_obs = t_xq_obs[:,0:3]

#%% Initialize Model
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = t_x_q_obs[:,0] #np.arange(0, 18/24+1e-6, 1/2*1/24)

# Declare parameter
V_liq   = m.Param(value = 159.0)

# Declare FVs
k_1     = m.FV(value = 0.80)
k_1.STATUS = 1
f_1     = m.FV(value = 10.0)
f_1.STATUS = 1

# Diff. Variables
X       = m.Var(value = 80.0) # at t=0
Y       = m.Var(value = 80.0*0.2)

rho_1   = m.Intermediate(k_1*X)
#q_prod  = m.Intermediate(0.52*f_1*X/24)
#X       = m.CV(value = t_x_q_obs[:,1])
q_prod  = m.CV(value = t_x_q_obs[:,2])

#%% Equations
m.Equations([X.dt() == -rho_1, Y.dt() == 0, q_prod == 0.52*f_1*X/24])

m.options.IMODE = 5
m.solve(disp=False)

#%% Plot some results
plt.plot(m.time, np.array(X.value)/10, label='X')
plt.plot(t_x_q_obs[:,0], t_x_q_obs[:,2], label='q_prod Meas.')
plt.plot(m.time, q_prod.value, label='q_prod Sim.')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('X / q_prod')
plt.grid()
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

> 0.0208333333  NaN 30.8306036
>   0.0416666667  NaN 29.1200832
>   0.0625    74.866  28.7700549
>   0.0833333333  NaN 29.2318865
>   0.104166667   NaN 30.7727362
>   0.125 NaN 29.8743804
>   0.145833333   NaN 29.9923447
>   0.166666667   NaN 30.9169679
>   0.1875    NaN 28.5956184
>   0.208333333   NaN 27.7361632
>   0.229166667   NaN 26.6669496
>   0.25  NaN 27.17477
>   0.270833333   75.751  23.6270346
>   0.291666667   NaN 23.0646928
>   0.3125    NaN 23.6442113
>   0.333333333   NaN 23.089118
>   0.354166667   NaN 22.9101616
>   0.375 NaN 22.7453854
>   0.395833333   NaN 23.2182759
>   0.416666667   NaN 21.4901903
>   0.4375    NaN 21.1449899
>   0.458333333   NaN 20.7093537
>   0.479166667   NaN 20.3109086
>   0.5   NaN 20.6825141
>   0.520833333   NaN 19.199583
>   0.541666667   NaN 19.6173416
>   0.5625    NaN 19.5543139
>   0.583333333   NaN 20.4501879
>   0.604166667   NaN 18.7678061
>   0.625 NaN 18.4629262
>   0.645833333   NaN 18.3730322
>   0.666666667   NaN 19.5375442
>   0.6875    NaN 18.1975297
>   0.708333333   NaN 18.0370627
>   0.729166667   NaN 17.5734727
>   0.75  NaN 18.8632046

So far, so good. Suppose I also have measurements of X (second column) at some time points (first column), the rest is not available (therefore `NaN`).
I would like to adjust `k_1` and `f_1`, so that simulated and observed variables `X` *and* `q_prod` match as closely as possible.

Is this feasible with Gekko? If so, how?

Another question: Gekko throws an error if `m.time` has more elements than there are time points of observed variables. However, my initial values of `X` and `Y` refer to `t=0`, not `t=0.0208333333`. Hence, the commented out part after `m.time =`, see above. (Measurements at `t=0` are not available.) Do initial conditions in Gekko refer to the first element of `m.time`, as they do in Matlab, or to `t=0`?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a missing measurement then you can include a non-numeric value such as NaN and Gekko ignores that entry in the objective function. Here is a test case with one NaN value in `ym`:

**Nonlinear Regression with NaN Data Value**

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xm = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5])
ym = np.array([0.1,0.2,np.nan,0.5,0.8,2.0])
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
x = m.Param(value=xm,name='x')
a = m.FV()
a.STATUS=1
y = m.CV(value=ym,name='y')
y.FSTATUS=1
m.Equation(y==0.1*m.exp(a*x))
m.options.IMODE = 2
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve(disp=True)
print('Optimized, a = ' + str(a.value[0]))
plt.plot(xm,ym,'bo')
plt.plot(xm,y.value,'r-')
m.open_folder()
plt.show()
```

When you open the run folder with `m.open_folder()` and look at the data file `gk_model0.csv`, there is the NaN in the `y` value column.

```
y,x
0.1,0
0.2,1
nan,2
0.5,3
0.8,4
2.0,5
```

This is `IMODE=2` so it is a steady state regression problem but shows the same thing that happens with dynamic estimation problems. There is [more information on the objective function](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/EstimatorObjective) with `m.options.EV_TYPE=1` (default) or `m.options.EV_TYPE=2` for estimation and how [bad values are handled in a data file](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/CSV). When the measurement is a non-numeric value, that bad value is dropped from the objective function summation. Here is a version with a dynamic model:

**Dynamic Regression with Fixed Initial Condition**

[image: Fixed Initial Condition]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xm = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5])
ym = np.array([2.0,1.5,np.nan,2.2,3.0,5.0])
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = xm
a = m.FV(lb=0.1,ub=2.0)
a.STATUS=1
y = m.CV(value=ym,name='y',fixed_initial=False)
y.FSTATUS=1
m.Equation(y.dt()==a*y)
m.options.IMODE = 5
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve(disp=True)
print('Optimized, a = ' + str(a.value[0]))
plt.figure(figsize=(6,2))
plt.plot(xm,ym,'bo',label='Meas')
plt.plot(xm,y.value,'r-',label='Pred')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.ylim([0,6])
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

As you observed, you need to have the same length for `m.time` as for your measurement values. If you are missing values then you can include append a `np.nan` to the beginning of the data horizon. By default, Gekko uses the first value specified in the `value` property to set the initial condition. If you don't want Gekko to use that value then set `fixed_initial=False` for your `CV`.

**Dynamic Regression with Free Initial Condition**

[image: Free initial condition]

```py
y = m.CV(value=ym,name='y',fixed_initial=False)
```